# location of ipmitool info?

Tags: linux, ipmitool, bmc

Does anyone know how to get this exact information through the command line/ipmitool vice this page.

Can't seem to locate it... I'm even trying to scrape the page (but that is a whole struggle of a lesson itself)...

any, even wild, ideas would be helpful... (hopefully it wasn't staring me in the face)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not have deals with IPMI. This information is from the [DMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Management_Interface), and can be read using `dmidecode` tool (as the name implies, on desktop computers too). Also, consider other utilities from the latter package, e.g. `biosdecode`.

Comment: This is helpful... I was focused on the BMC, don't know why I didn't look elsewhere. dmidecode gives me what I need so I will probably take this as the answer.. but I will probably use ansible as to solve the problem since i just found that it also spits this out... (depending on if it faster to have ansible 'gather facts' or have ansible run dmidecode).... Thanks, this put me on the right track (and to my dismay, it was right in front of me)